# how to check where the searched word exist using preg_match and array in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

i have a php code that read text files and allow the user to make a search then it display the result in an html  table that contains **filename** and **line number** each file can handle multiple lines.

all txt files composed of 10 categories where each category contains some text in it.

[image]

**the array will contain the categories that all txt files are composed of it so i thought that in order to check where the searched word exist and as the categories are standards and do not change for that i use the array where the txt file content is the searched word(if exist) + the array elements + other text.**

the expected result:

[image]

i know that i must includes these categories in an **array**  and while the system read read the files it make a compare with the array's element  once it found a match it display the category name beside the line number.

i do not know how to write this idea in php can anyone help me ?

## code:

```
    <?php

    $result = [];
    if(isset($_POST["search"]))
    {
        $search =$_POST['name'];
        echo "the word  $search exist: <br><br>";
        foreach(glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/readfiletest/*.txt") as $txts)
        {
            $categories = ["محلي", "إقليمي","دولي"];
            $line = 1;
            $temp   = [];
            $myFileLink = fopen($txts, 'r');
            while(!feof($myFileLink))
            {
                $myFileContents = fgets($myFileLink);
                if( preg_match_all('/('.preg_quote($search,'/').')/i', $myFileContents, $matches))
                {

                    if(preg_match('/'.preg_quote($categories[0], '/'). '/u', $myFileContents))
                    {
                        echo "the category found is $categories[0]"; 
                    }
                }
                ++$line;
            }
            fclose($myFileLink);
    }
?>
```

Comment: See `if(preg_match($categories[0],$myFileContents))` - the `$categories` do not contain valid regexps, they are just strings. Use regex delimiters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok i  correct the array and put regex delimiters  but id did not display the requested result

Comment: If the patterns contain Unicode chars, add `u` modifier. `/i` => `/ui`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so how to put it in the if statement ?

Comment: `preg_match_all('/('.preg_quote($search,'/').')/ui'` and `if(preg_match('/'.preg_quote($categories[0], '/') . '/u',$myFileContents))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i used your answer but still nothing is displayed in the echo

Comment: Then there is only 1 way to proceed: please provide the [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i will edit my question in order to provide the MCVE take a look to the question.

Comment: I still cannot make the code run. What is a sample `$search` value?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  the $search value is سابقا

Comment: Good, so, the text you have does not contain this value, see https://ideone.com/hSfGZO, thus there is no match.

Comment: the problem is that all these readed files conatin  this value .... and what i want from this task is to be able to check where the searched word exist in which array element... i do not know if you understand my question

Comment: let change the element array for category 1 and category 2 and the value of  $search = الماء what will be the result ??

Comment: Let me reopen the question since it is no longer the dupe of the mentioned question, but I do not really know what you mean. If you want to filter an array to find items containing a string, I suspect you may use `preg_grep` - `preg_grep('/' . preg_quote($search, '/') . '/ui', $arr)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i tried your answer and it did not give the right answer... it display this result :**the تعقيدات، found under category 1**

=============
after i changed $categories = ["category 1", "category 2", "category 3"];
$search = 'تعقيدات،';

what the expected result is : the تعقيدات، found under category 2

Comment: i have multiple of TEXT files that the system read from it and the content of all files is divided into 10 categories==== what i want is to make the system search for requested word from the user ==== and to take into consideration the categories that exist in the content === where the result must be like this :
============
the searched word exist  in this filename-- at this line--- under this category.
=======
for that i am thinking that i need to use an array and the preg_match .

is this wrong ?

Comment: If you just need to get lines containing words regardless of content, you might do without a regex, just use [`mb_stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php) when iterating through the lines.

Comment: i did not understand your last comment